# Multipart file upload failing some times on docker container on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, multipartform-data, hapi.js

I have an hapi server running on AWS docker container and it exposes a file upload API. This API runs smoothly on my local machine, but when deployed to AWS it fails some times with an error "Incomplete multipart payload". The error does not occur always, but only at some times.
The images which I am uploading are small in size(less than 100 kb) only and this failure is not because of slow network as I have tested it on multiple networks.

After debugging hapi modules for payload parsing, I have found that Pez module who is parsing the payload is throwing this error. I also noticed that when this error happens Pez modules onClose event is called and none of the parse events occurs and hence it returns the "Incomplete multipart payload" error. The Pez state is at "preamble" when this happens, for successful parse case, the state is "epilogue".

My hapi route config is

```
config: {
        payload: {
          maxBytes: 20971520,
          output: 'data',
          parse: true,
          allow: 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      }
```

Can somebody suggest why is the parsing fails at times or why the onClose event is called before parsing happens?